# Windows 10: Application doesn't require Administrator authentication. I want to make said Application require Administrator authentication

Tags: windows-10, administrator, uac

In Windows 10 I have Application that doesn't require Administrator authentication to run. I want to make said Application require Administrator authentication to run.

I've searched but only found topics on how to run a application that requires Administrator authentication without the authentication.

Iv'e compared the security permissions on both exe and they appear the same, and that was the end of my knowledge on this subject so I'm unsure of how to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: select the application exe, select properties->compatibility and set the checkbox to require admin rights

Comment: You do realize that anyone with admin rights will be able to undo whatever solution you implement.

Comment: You will have to modify the manfest file for the application.

Comment: @Twisty: This is my PC, the application are for SSH/PGP key purposes so I want another layer (the admin password/UAC) to be required to open them. There is only on admin account and there no are plans to change that. My normal user doesn't run under the admin account.

Comment: @magicandre1981: Thanks! that worked perfectly.!

Comment: @Tempster102 Sounds good. Just wanting to clarify that point since normally the purpose for requiring admin rights is to prevent *unauthorized* use (implying use by other users).

Answer (score 0):

As posted by magicandre1981: select the application exe, select properties->compatibility and set the checkbox to require admin rights –